# AnimeJS path animate

Tags: javascript, anime.js

Я анимирую движение блока по кругу с помощью animejs

```js
let a = anime.path('svg circle')


let b = anime({
  targets: 'p',
  translateX: a('x'),
  translateY: a('y'),
  easing: 'linear',
  duration: 2000,
  loop: true,
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>

  <p>text</p>
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle class="circleAnime" cx="123.945" cy="123.945" r="75.445" transform="rotate(-90 123.945 123.945)" stroke="#5FE4BF" stroke-width="73"/>

</svg>
```

Однако я бы хотел останавливать в любом месте по пути
при этом анимация должна заканчиваться тоесть pause() не подходит

Comment: Так а вопрос-то в чем заключается, какие ответы он предполагает?

Comment: Пойдет пример как можно остановить блок в середине пути например

Comment: в документации очень коротко говорится о anime.path объекте может с его помощью можно это как то сделать

Comment: _«пример как можно остановить блок в середине пути например»_ - к сожалению, такое практически всегда заканчивается цепочкой "но мне не это надо!" в комментах под ответами, поэтому я заранее сдаюсь))) и советую все-таки определиться с условиями своей задачи (указав их в вопросе), пока минусов не насыпали. А в общем и целом, операция "стоп" в этой библиотеке выполняется последовательным вызовом методов `pause` и `seek` (т.е.: пауза, и затем перемотка в начало. Альтернативных способов мне неизвестно).